# Scraping data from a table or list?

Tags: javascript, php, web, screen-scraping

I want to scrap table data from this website

https://escapehunt.com/uk/birmingham/booking

i am trying this code, please help me.

```
<?php

include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('https://escapehunt.com/uk/birmingham/booking');

foreach($html->find('td[class="cbgridfirst"]') as $element){
echo $element->innertext . '<br>'; 

} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $`element ->textContent` 
instead of `innertext`

Answer (score 0):

It not working because the website uses an embedded frame and it load data dynamically. Please tell me any method.

Comment: In that case I would suggest editing your question and title, or even starting an entirely new question which includes all the relevant information.